# Triangulation of Polygons in a binary Mask

Tags: python, computational-geometry, triangulation, delaunay

I´m currently working on a project to measure the surface of plant leaves. Until now I´ve successfully implemented an RCNN model to segment individual leaves and also generated a depth map using stereo computer vision which allows me to calculate distances between any two points.

Now I´m stuck trying to connect everything together in order to calculate the area of a leaf/polygon.

**I got original RGB images, Binary masks containing leaves, and also the depth information of every pixel.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?**

I reckon the right way would be to use Delauney triangulation on the polygons in the binary masks and then calculate the surface using the distance between the 3 points of each triangle. I haven't been able to find something quite similar to my problem which is implemented in python.

Thanks so much for your help in advance. I´ll upload a picture of an RGB image with the masks plotted.
[leaf instance segmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iPpo.png)

Comment: "the right way would be to use Delauney triangulation on the polygons in the binary masks and then calculate the surface using the distance between the 3 points of each triangle": what ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust I apologize, I should have used the word guess before that. It was, indeed my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Count the pixels inside the outlines (by polygon filling) or use the shoelace formula.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, it already points me in the right direction. After reading your comment I realize that I asked my question wrongly. If you look at the picture I uploaded, you may see that I need to calculate the area of rather organic shapes. Having said that I would very much appreciate it if you could point out the whole process for me as I´m having trouble visualizing it myself. From binary masks of these organic shapes to having the ara of their surface in meters. Thank you very much, @Yves Daoust

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: I understand your answer. But what I´m asking for is how to calculate the surface in meters after having counted the pixels, having in mind that those pixels have different depths. And if you could provide me with an example or reference I would deeply appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @KailKuhn: I missed that this is a 3D problem. As the geometry is that of a grid, trigulation is immediate. You obtain the triangle sides by Pythagoras, and the triangle areas by the Heron formula. If your Z data is noisy, the computed area will be overestimated and you'd better denoise of fit smooth patches.